# How to use wildcard pattern in DSpace xmlui sitemap?

Tags: java, sitemap, apache-cocoon, dspace

I modified the feedback form (xmlui) to pass and display the item's title. I would like to follow the behaviour of DSpace jspui recommend item feature where the url upon clicking the "Recommend this item" link, it would generate the url `http://example.com/suggest?handle=12345/123`. In my case, I would like to generate the url: `http://example.com/feedback?handle=12345/123`. I noticed that if I'll just use:

`Division feedback = body.addInteractiveDivision("feedback-form",
contextPath + "/feedback/" + parameters.getParameter("handle","unknown"),Division.METHOD_POST,"primary");`

and set the sitemap to `<map:match pattern="feedback/**">`, it will return the url as `http://example.com/feedback/handle/12345/123`. What if I want to change the url into `http://example.com/feedback?handle=12345/123`? I modified the sitemap to use `<map:match pattern="feedback**">` and `<map:match pattern="feedback?handle=**">`. I have of course edited the appropriate xsl file to generate the link for the url but my problem is that I either get "not page found" or the handle and title is not passed when I submit the form. I have read [here](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.0/userdocs/matchers/matchers.html) that

> A string containing two asterisks ('**') matches zero or more characters.

I wonder why `feedback/**` worked but not `feedback**` and `feedback?handle=**`. Please advise on what steps I have to make and file(s) I have to change to generate the url: `http://example.com/feedback?handle=12345/123`?

Comment: I originally posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064830/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-the-referring-page-item-from-a-modified-version-of) but my main concern that time was to display/pass the item's title and it was resolved. I'm thinking I should post a separate question here.

Comment: `<map:match pattern="feedback">` should work. Anything after the '?' does not have to be matched. If you say the "the handle and title is not passed" then there is another problem